# How does a rectifier demodulate radio information and why does its capacitance matter?

Tags: diodes, demodulation

I read in a forum “A point contact diode like OA79 should be used for the demodulation of AM. This diode is a signal diode and is having a low junction capacitance because of its special construction. If a rectifier diode is used for this purpose, the junction capacitance may form an undesirable leakage path ( a bypass) across the diode because the carrier is a RF ( IF in the detector).”

I don’t quite understand what is meant.

How does a diode demodulate the radio signals and why its capacitance matters? Can this be answered with a simple circuit model?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/radio/modulation/am-diode-detector-demodulator.php

Comment: Thanks for the link. Why does diode capacitance matter ?

Comment: The diode capacitance provides a path through the diode for the RF. Imagine a diode and capacitor in parallel. Some of the RF signal can pass through the capacitor at relatively low impedance instead of going through the diode.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. Exactly what @TonyM said.

Comment: @TonyM:  That's the start of an answer.  Want to finish the job?

Comment: @TonyM I dont understand. There is a LP cap after the rectifier. Even the diode passes carrier freq. wouldnt the LP filter already remove that carrier??

Comment: You can look up a hot carrier or Schottky diode in low current rating but an OpAmp and diode may work better as an ideal rectifier with gain.

Comment: @JRE, not really, busy working - hence a comment. But since you've got time on your hands, step in...

Comment: @Genzo You really should study the pages (before and after, as well as on the one given) provided by esilk. These will answer all of your questions, perhaps with the exception of the main one about the advantages of a point-contact diode. By the way, they are easy to make. A good quality galena crystal (mine from South America) and a few ounces of lead; immerse the crystal in molten lead and allow to cool. A tiny needle touching the crystal works, but you need to test it with different points on the crystal for better results. (You can make your own galena, too, from pure lead and sulfur.)